# ExtJS 4 Combobox event for selecting selected value

Tags: javascript, combobox, extjs4

For some reason I need to know when user has selected value from combobox even if it is already selected. "Select" event works only if user selects unselected item. I don't see any event like "itemclick" in the docs for combobox or picker. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ComboBox` uses [BoundList](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.BoundList) for representing dropdown list. `BoundList` fires [itemclick](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.BoundList-event-itemclick) event. You can use `ComboBox`'s [listConfig](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-listConfig) config in order to setup `BoundList` listeners:

```js
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    // ...
    listConfig: {
        listeners: {
            itemclick: function(list, record) {
                alert(record.get('name') + ' clicked');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check out the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/Gzp86/).